# Increase initial amount of the free memory in an Android application

Tags: java, android, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'd like to know if this is possible. My purpose is to decrease the number of GC operations during a long processing.

---

In an Android application I check the free and max heap size with:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

System.out.println( "freeMemory: " + runtime.freeMemory() );
System.out.println( "maxMemory: " + runtime.maxMemory() );
System.out.println( "memoryClass: " + am.getMemoryClass() );
```

In LogCat for the `onCreate()` method it says:

```
freeMemory: 5678992
maxMemory: 50331648
memoryClass: 48
```

Then I perform some long `String` operations and in the middle of the processing I check the memory again:

```
freeMemory: 1833176
```

(I don't post the code of this processing because for the actual stage I don't perform the `Java` code optimization, only working with the memory).

And the GC runs to free the memory. This slows the application:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 4760K, 42% free 7653K/13123K, paused 12ms+13ms, total 43ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 2012K, 42% free 7688K/13123K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 31ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 1839K, 42% free 7662K/13123K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 40ms
```

At the end of the processing the free memory is:

```
freeMemory: 4605040
```

---

As the documentation says:

- `Runtime.freeMemory()`

  > Returns the number of bytes currently available on the heap without expanding the heap.
- `Runtime.maxMemory()`

  > Returns the maximum number of bytes the heap can expand to.

As I understand the `Runtime.maxMemory()` shows the memory which shouldn't be overflowed to prevent the `OutOfMemoryError`. And exceeding the `Runtime.freeMemory()` amount just leads to the free memory expanding.

So the GC freeing operations in my code were caused by the low amount of the free memory left after memory consuming actions (when it said: `freeMemory: 1 833 176`). But the total amount of the free memory wasn't expanded, only freed to stay within the same starting limit.

And I suppose the initial amount of the free memory also wasn't very high (because in the `onCreate()` method it showed `5 678 992`). And if I had initially about 10 MB free the GC wouldn't happen and thus the application would perform the processing faster.

---

**So the question is:** Is there a way I can increase the initial amount of the free memory to prevent frequent GC calls and memory expanding?

Thanks.

Comment: From your users' standpoint, it would be better to reduce GC by not generating quite as much garbage in the first place (e.g., avoids extra constructor calls, does not waste system RAM). Since you have not posted the code for the "long processing", it is difficult to assist you with that.

Comment: I understand that I have to optimize the code. But it's a separate question about `String` processing... Here I'd like to know if (in this case) to reduce GC calls I can only work with the initial `5MB` of memory (limiting the number of created objects) or I could expand it to `10MB`.

Comment: you're understand of the GC is not very correct. There're a lot of calls to the **Garbage Collector** because your operation is generating a lot of garbage. It doesn't matter how much memory was available, to reduce GC one must reduce garbage. On the other hand, you don't have to start with a bigger heap to be able to allocate more. In case you run out of HEAP memory during this "long processing" the system will allocate more HEAP for you, and that operation is 100% transparent for you.

Comment: As I understand my starting heap size is what the `Runtime.freeMemory()` returns say in the `onCreate()` method (I mean "starting heap" - the heap before my own operations but after the system loads all app components). That's the size I may occupy with my objects during the app lifecycle. Are these thoughts right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use in your Mainifast.xml this attribute

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: Thanks. But I already have enough heap size: `getMemoryClass()` shows `48MB`. But before the GC calls I used only about `5MB`.